# When I transfer from my master view to my detail view after adding a new item, my detail view is empty

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios6

I'm making a sample app to learn iOS dev, and I have the app create default items to populate the tableview originally, and you can add further ones as well.

If I tap on the default ones (well, there's only one) and segue to the detail view it shows all the details (Name, Location and Date) as intended. But if I add a new one, it comes up with those fields being Empty.

I can't figure out why. I have seemingly all the view refreshing methods set, and it should be setting the detail view's data object which then feeds the labels.

Could anyone help? I'd supply further code if requested, I just don't know what to supply now as I'm not sure exactly where the problem is. It's a rather simple app, though.

Project available here: http://cl.ly/3N0o272M3y1K

Comment: I had a look at your project - I can see what you are trying to do, but how did you get to this place? Are you following a tutorial? The code "parts" make sense and therefore you do not have any errors, but the design does not really work. - When you press the done button, it sends the data to your source Controller, but the detailViewController can't pick it up, because there is no storage medium.

Comment: Also you are declaring and shifting the contents of objects a bit, so it easy to loose track of your structure. Hold on a tick

Comment: When i said a tick - wait I until I post the answer:-)

Comment: Why do you use 2NavigationController?

Comment: He uses them, so he can do a modal transition (pushing up) from there he can then navigate to other points.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this took a bit longer than planned - but it is a good way to learn.

I have attached the project in a zip file.

The code is a bit different then what you posted, but if you compare them side by side, you will see how they are planned and build differently.

It shows the Segue working within the Storyboard.

There where 2 big problems with your project outside of your misuses of the methods.

- You need something like Core Data if you want your data to be persistant. In the example I have given you I have used Plist, this will do the trick, but is not persistant in this case.
- Also your detailViewController had no labels for the text to appear, so you will need to look into Custom Cells for that - to match your design.

Good Luck and I hope this is useful:-)

[Updated Project](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/61711378/BirdWatching.zip)

Comment: Oh wow, thank you, I'm going to take a look through your posting.

Comment: My only question would be that, yes, I did follow this tutorial: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html it's from Apple and I thought I followed it to a T. (My code looks identical to their Final Code Postings.) There's seemingly worked...

Comment: Ha I have never read through all off that:-) It is probably not wrong, I just learned through trial and error, so I still have a long way to go;-)